# How georeference image on Delphi?

Tags: delphi, bitmap, kml

I have a bitmap, my user set 2 or more marker on the image, then for any marker set latitude and langitude.
With this imformation I must create a Ground Overlays for a KML file, so I need know how can I calculate the LatLonBox parameter: north, south, east, west and rotation for the bitmap.

Any ideas?

This is a example of the resut:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Folder>
    <name>Ground Overlays</name>
    <description>Examples of ground overlays</description>
    <GroundOverlay>
      <name>Large-scale overlay on terrain</name>
      <description>Overlay shows Mount Etna erupting on July 13th, 2001.</description>
      <Icon>
        <href>http://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/images/etna.jpg</href>
      </Icon>
      <LatLonBox>
        <north>37.91904192681665</north>
        <south>37.46543388598137</south>
        <east>15.35832653742206</east>
        <west>14.60128369746704</west>
        <rotation>-0.1556640799496235</rotation>
      </LatLonBox>
     </GroundOverlay>
  </Folder>
</kml>
```

My problem are the north, south, east, west and rotation value.
In fact my user must load a image then he put 2 or more markers on it and for all markers set latitude and longitude. With this data I think it's possible get north, south, east, west and rotation value but I don't know how.
If the user put only 2 markers it's easy, I can calculate dX and dY then north, south, east and west (in this case I set rotation = 0), but if the user set more that 2 points?

Comment: It would be nice if you show what you've tried. This question feels like it's only half written down.  I feel its unkind to downvote, so I avoid doing so, but this question could use a little more effort.

Comment: Can you add some more information? It's not clear what you have now and what you need. If you describe those better, we can help you out better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is too long for a comment so I'll write it as an answer (I did try writing it as comment twice!). First let's deal with the number of markers you'll get on the map: in a perfect world two markers should be all you need, because geometrically they're all you need to subsequently derive the coordinates for *any* other point on the map. That means that the 3rd marker should be *redundant*, it's exact coordinates could be calculated using the coordinates for the first two points. You imply that using an 3rd point you could extract "rotation", but that's plain wrong, because the map is 2D! Here's an example of a rotated rectangle that's perfectly defined using two points:

**What the user marks on the map:**

[image]

**How that information is interpreted:**
[image]

The moment you get the 3rd point from the same rectangle you get the chance to do some "error correction". Let's assume you want to extract the precise coordinates for the top-left corner of your rectangle. Two points are mathematically all you need in order to compute that. The moment you get 3 points (let's call those points A, B and C), you can calculate the same coordinate using 3 equations:

```
(A,B) => P1
(A,C) => P2
(B,C) => P3
```

... and you're practically guaranteed to get 3 distinct values (P1, P2 and P3) for the coordinates of your top-left corner! You'll now need to apply some error-correction math in order to "merge" the 3 distinct values into just one value. This kind of error correction is often done in the real-world for geodesics (those guys with the yellow tripods that do geodesic maps, you'll see them on all the construction work sites). If you want the correct solution you could look into that, or you could simply average the 3 values and be done with it, it's most likely good enough for your needs.

The requested output XML seems to define the image rectangle using TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT and ROTATION coordinates. In order to transform your coordinates into that format you'll need to figure out what the target software does with the XML. If I were to guess it would go something like this: The image is first placed on the map in the space defined by the top/bottom/left/right coordinates, it's then rotated the given amount. If that's true, this is what I'd do to prepare your bitmap:

1. First determine the coordinates for the top-left corner, top-right corner and bottom-right corner. By now it should be clear that two points are enough for that, but if you get more then two points, figure out an error-correction scheme and use all the points to get more precision.
2. Using the top-left and top-right corner coordinates calculate your current rotation.
3. Figure out the coordinates for the center of rotation point used by the target SOFTWARE. Does the target software rotate the image around it's center? Does it rotate the image around the top-left corner? Anyhow, calculate the coordinates for that point.
4. Rotate your coordinates around the CENTER you calculated at (3) using the rotation angle you got at (2) in order to make your image parallel to the horizontal axes.
5. Take the NORTH and WEST from the rotated top-left corner, take the SOUTH and EAST from your bottom-right corner. You got your rotation angle at (2) so by now you've got a complete solution.